# Convert imap files to pst file

Tags: imap, pst

I have a lot of ".imap" files (around 1000) from old IceWarp server and I need to open them somehow. I think that the best way is to convert all files to single pst file and open it in outlook, but I can't find any tool for that. So does someone have some idea how to do that please? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

IceWarp `.imap` and `.tmp` files are really just text files which contain a message in the standard RFC 2822 format, so their handling is similar to Mbox or Maildir formats.

The easiest way to open the messages to **rename them to have an `.eml` extension,** as they're already in the correct format for that. Then you can just double-click an .eml file to open an individual message through Outlook (personally I would prefer Thunderbird).

You can also drag & drop .eml files directly into Outlook/Thunderbird and they'll be imported as messages (uploaded to a mailserver, or written to a local PST file).

---

> I think that the best way is to convert all files to single pst file and open it in outlook, but I can't find any tool for that

As far as I know, there is no "convert to PST" tool for email messages in general – I only know of one program capable of generating PST files, and that's Outlook itself.

However, Outlook can open other kinds of mail files, not just PST files. If your goal is to open the messages in Outlook *somehow*, then you don't need a PST file for that – there are easier ways.

So if all you need is to open the messages somehow, this isn't "the best way", this is actually going to be a very backwards way of doing it.

But if you *specifically* need a PST file, then use the instructions found above to import the messages to Outlook and *then* it'll generate a PST file for you.

---

Alternative instructions for people who prefer using Mutt/Neomutt on Linux:

1. Create a new directory (let's say "icewarp").
2. Create three subdirectories `cur`, `new`, and `tmp` inside that directory.
3. Move all IceWarp ".imap" files to the "icewarp/new/" subdirectory.
4. Now you have a *Maildir*-format mailbox that various Linux tools will accept.
5. Run `mutt -f icewarp/` to open the Maildir and browse messages.